# Multiple math operations on timeseries data using groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe/series containing hourly sampled data over a couple of years. I'd like to sum the values for each month, then calculate the mean of those monthly totals over all the years.
I can get a multi-index dataframe/series of the totals using:

```
df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month]).sum()

Date & Time  Date & Time
2016         3              220.246292
             4              736.204574
             5              683.240291
             6              566.693919
             7              948.116766
             8              761.214823
             9              735.168033
             10             771.210572
             11             542.314915
             12             434.467037
2017         1              728.983901
             2              639.787918
             3              709.944521
             4              704.610437
             5              685.729297
             6              760.175060
             7              856.928659
```

But I don't know how to then combine the data to get the means.
I might be totally off on the wrong track too. Also not sure I've labelled the question very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `mean` per years - so per first level:

```
df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month]).sum().mean(level=0)
```

Comment: Thanks. Guess I need to learn about using level.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` twice, once to get the monthly sum, once to get the mean of monthly sum:

```
(df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).sum()
   .groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='Y')).mean()
)
```